# Running a Jar on remote machines via SSH

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to execute a java jar on multiple machines on the same time, I have the machines ips and usernames in a file called peers list, so I wrote the following code :

```
    while read line 
    do 
        ip="$(echo $line | cut -d: -f2)"
        username="$(echo $line | cut -d: -f3)"
        torrent="$(echo $line | cut -d: -f6)"
    ssh $username@$ip java -jar experiment/SimpleDownloader.jar $torrent & 
  done < peerslist
```

However the program was running on just the first machine, I've later understood it's a problem with ssh inside loops so I've added the option  `> /dev/null` to the ssh command. Now the Java program runs on all the machines but it keeps running although it's supposed to finish after a certain time.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with a program, not with a script? When you log in an run the jar manually, does it stop after expected period of time?

Comment: Hi Ala, try enclosing the ssh command in (double) quotes: depending on your version of ssh that should fix it. Also, use & inside or outside quotes to control where the fork happens.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I found the solution. Just added -n option to the ssh command and removed the > /dev/null and it worked, don't even know why or how but it worked :D